# Accessing Item Inside RxSwift

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift and I am trying to access individual items inside my subscribe function. But the .subscribe gives me the array of ShoppingList and I want an individual ShoppingList item.

```
private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

var shoppingLists :Variable<[ShoppingList]> = Variable([])

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // add to the shoppinglist
    let shoppingList = ShoppingList(title: "Walmart")
    self.shoppingLists.value.append(shoppingList)


    shoppingLists.asObservable()
       .subscribe { shoppingLists in

            // how to access the item inside the shoppingList // Walmart

            print("subscribe")
            print(shoppingLists)
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shoppingLists.asObservable()
   .flatMap { shoppingList in
       Observable.from(shoppingList) // <- magic here
   }
   .subscribe(onNext: { item in
        print("subscribe")
        print(item)
    })
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: is there a combine version of this?